# Check if post has attachments (not image)

Tags: attachments, images

Need to do a check if post has attachments that are not images.
I haven't seen this anywhere - thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to check if the post has an attachment other than image (or other mime types):

```
        <?php $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => 'image'
        ));


        if ( $attachments ) { ?>
               // do something
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following within a loop:

```
$files = get_attached_media( $type, $post_id );
```

Just define the attachment MIME type on `$type`. Second parameter is optional. Example from the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media):

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'audio', 102 );
```

With the retrieved array, you can do something like:

```
if( $media ) {
   //Show the post attachments that are not images, but audio
}
```

Comment: hey thanks. I should specify, I'm looking for documents - .doc, .txt. .pdf, etc.

Comment: Check this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files, and upload your files. After uploading check the database, and to the `posts` table. Check the `post_mime_type` to see the exact MIME type of your file. And it can be any. :)